# Why is it bad to develop on a testserver?

Tags: php, testing, xampp, environment

At our current project we have 1. a production server, 2. a test server and 3. several developers using xampp under Windows. Prod- and Testserver are run by UNIX.

One of the other developers is repeatedly complaining about us using xampp under windows. He's saying that we should create a v-server on the test-environment for developing purposes (maybe one v-server for each developer, I don't quite know). To me, this feels just awfully wrong. But I can't really explain why, except obvious reasons like you have to connect to the remote dev-server, etc.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com We would love to, but he is on the customer's side.

Comment: I agree that it is better to have a local installation, mainly for reduced latency, to ensure that one user doesn't overwrite someone else's work, and of course to be able to work offline. That all said, if he is on the customer's side, you may have to help him out as if he were the customer himself. Setting up a separate test installation for his "local" dev should be easy, but let him (and the customer) know of the downsides.

Comment: "should be easy" - yeah, you don't know the application. he "developed" it all by himself, ignoring all best practices and never using branches, copy-pasting code, hardcoding passwords, etc. He did his best to ensure that this thing only works on the prod-server and nowhere else. But that's another story ;)

Comment: @user1673524: ouch; that exactly reminds me of an ex-colleague! Your problem is more of a diplomatic/managerial one than anything else; you need a meeting to improve application resilience, and to agree a basic standards doc with his line managers. Even better if you can have some unit or functional tests to check the quality of everyone's work in a non-judgmental way. (Aside: don't forget to use [at]username to ping people here - I just chanced upon your reply).

Comment: @halfer he is 56 years old and pretty stubborn. before we were consulted, he was just developing on the production-server. given that the application handles extremely sensitive data (personell information, etc), we had to change that first. but he doesn't understand why. we tried it the diplomatic way, now I'm kind of coding the thing new from scratch.

Comment: @shnoop - ok. Ensure that they are well aware of the work you're doing, otherwise it can "tread on toes" and offend. Be as inclusive as you can with developers of poor quality, otherwise they can turn into loose cannons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I do it.  There are 4 stages.

1) Local server.  Here, you can work on your own changes, feature branches, etc.  Do your work, make sure it works on your machine, and then request it get pulled into the development branch.

2) Dev Server.  This is a carbon copy of whatever's in the development branch, and is meant as a means to see how your code is a) working in an actual environment and b) playing with other people's code.

3) "Test Server", which is where QA should be done.  The settings on this server should be as close to those on Production as possible. and allow for all the bug fixes, features, and improvements you've been working on to be looked over and either resolved or reported back on.

4) Production.  By the time the code makes it here, it should be stable and ready to go.  This should be the "final product" for the client (even if you're still fixing bugs / doing maintenance)

Comment: With step 2), it actually makes sense. We are missing a dev-server at the moment. Thanks! But what are the underlying priciples? Security, Stability, ...?

Comment: What Alex Hart refers to as a "Dev Server" here is roughly what is known as "Continuous Integration", which implies using tools to automate test builds, run unit tests, update automated documentation, etc.

Comment: okay that may be a bit too advanced for what we are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're less likely to get a surprise when you move between environments (dev to test to live) if the environments are all configured as similarly as possible.

Running PHP under Windows via XAMPP will lead to subtle differences in behaviour compared to running it on a Unix/Linux based server. Having to deal with these adds unnecessary overhead to your development, and increases the risk of bugs not being spotted soon enough.

Running virtual servers in your office allows you to continue using Windows desktops, but run your code on an accurate simulation of your production servers even as you're writing it. It can also simplify the sysadmin's job because they don't have to manage lots of separate PCs when you need to upgrade PHP, set up backups, etc.

As for the inconvenience, this isn't that big a deal if you use "samba" - the files on the development server are accessible as a Windows fileshare, so you carry on editing them just like you would if they were on your own machine. Pretty much the only time you need to connect to the server directly (over SSH) is when you change the Apache configuration and need to restart/reload the daemon for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Okay so it's probably not that of a bad idea. Only problem is, that we want to be able to develop offline.

Comment: @shnoop What do you mean by "offline"? Are you using laptops and want to be able to use them outside of the office, or are you assuming that the dev server would be in a remote data centre? A dev server would generally be in a corner of your office, connected straight to your LAN, not the internet.

Answer (score 0):

One benefit of managing a dedicated development environment is that you can implement an automated build process that redeploys the dev server on a regular schedule. This increases the likelihood of discovering incompatible changes earlier in the development cycle.